# array issues when using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

I am trying to use ajax to compare two arrays to see if a particular value set is  the same or not, so I filled both arrays with the same values and when i tested them  my test says that they are not the same.  The first array was made on fileA.php (with a while loop pulling directly from a database)and uses ajax to send it as a url variable to fileB.php (the responding file). On fileB.php I then use a $_GET to get the array , and create another array with a while loop pulling the exact same values directly from the database and compare the two . At this point the two arrays should be the same, but as I said earlier my test says they aren't .So I did a var_dump of both arrays and they looked different for some reason.

first array dump:

```
    array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [1]=>
   string(6)     ",2,2,1"
 }
```

second array dump:

```
array(3) {
 [0]=>
 array(0) {
 }
 [1]=>
 string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
 }
```

array 1 is made on fileA.php

```
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
 {

    $iState[] = $row["state"];
 }///end while
```

then i use ajax to send to fileB.php

```
   js_array=<? echo json_encode($iState); ?>;

   var url_js_array=js_array.join(',');

    xmlhttp.open("GET","fileB.php?istate="+ url_js_array,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

then in fileB.php(ajax response file) i retrieve the array

```
    $iStateValues[] =$_GET["istate"] ;
```

then I create array 2 on fileB.php

```
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
   {

     $currentiState[]= $row["state"];

      }///end while
```

then I compred the two

```
   echo"\n\nsame test\n";
   if($iStateValues==$currentiState)
   echo "same";
   else
   echo "not same";
```

The var_dumps of the two arrays are different but they were created the exact same way .  Wh is this?????

Comment: I know you mentioned you're running a while loop and building the arrays directly, but could you give us the code to examine?

Comment: i updated my post with the code....

Comment: The problem lies with json_encode and javascript join. That is were you modify the array. You should not use the join function and instead later use json_decode($_GET["istate"]);

Answer (score -1):

Your arrays are not the same, actually. Your first array (lets, say `$arr1`) has 2 elements, while your second array (lets, say `$arr2`) has 4 elements in it.

Definitely, the first element of both the arrays (i.e., `$arr1[0]` and `$arr2[0]`) is an empty array and that part of the arrays are similar.

Now, the remaining part of the first array (i.e. `$arr1[1]`) is a string: `",2,2,1"`, while the remaining part of the second array are more array values: `2, 2, 1` and is not a string.

i.e.:

```
$arr1[1] #=> string: ,2,2,1
$arr2[1] #=> string: 2
$arr2[2] #=> string: 2
$arr2[3] #=> string: 1
```

And, therefore, you can clearly see the two arrays are not equal.

You can compare two arrays for equality (preserving the order) using the `===` operator, like this:

```
$arr1 === $arr2 #=> false
```

If you only want to check whether the two arrays have the same values (irrespective of their order), you should use the `==` operator.

Comment: Yeah I saw that but i made the arrays the same way....Why would they be different???

Comment: I see your point but I used the same method to create both....ill add some code above to explain...

Comment: yeah, that will definitely help.

Comment: == is critical here because array(0,1) == array(1,0) returns true but would not mean the same in his example...

Comment: @andreas: yeah, you are correct on that part. updated the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Your arrays are not equal because you modify them in your code!

PHP:

```
// This is not an array, but a json string
js_array=<? echo json_encode($iState); ?>;
```

JS:

```
// Just pass the whole json string and don't use join!
xmlhttp.open("GET","fileB.php?istate="+ url_js_array,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

PHP:

```
// Create an array again with json_decode
$iStateValues[] = json_decode($_GET["istate"]);
```

---

To your second question, this is how you could compare arrays in PHP:

```
$array1 = array(1, 2, 3); // This is the same like $array1 = array(0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3);
$array2 = array(1, 2, 4);
$array3 = array(3, 2, 1);

var_dump($array1 == $array2); // false
var_dump($array1 == $array3); // false
var_dump($array2 == $array3); // true

var_dump($array1 === $array2); // false
var_dump($array1 === $array3); // false
var_dump($array2 === $array3); // false
```

"==" checks for the same elements and "===" for the correct order. So in your case, '===' would deliver the correct answer.

Comment: Why downvote? The op did not ask a clear question, hence I posted a way to compare PHP arrays. I added a suggestion how to fix the code issue now.